# Do the Baire Sets of $\mathbb{R}$ contain the Borel Sets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to gain some intuitive characterization of the Baire subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  I've seen different definitions of Baire subsets (which I presume are equivalent) but here is a characterization from Royden:

The Baire subsets of $X$ (denoted $\mathcal{B}$) are equivalent to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{G_\delta\}$ where $G_\delta$ is a countable intersection of open subsets of $X$.

If $X = \mathbb{R}$, wouldn't then $\mathcal{B}$ contain the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ since any open set $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is also a $G_\delta$ so that since the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ generate the Borel Sets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ would at least contain the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: Maybe you can check all the definitions of Baire measurable in this case.

Comment: Also not to be confused with the collection of sets that have the [property of Baire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_baire), which is *also* a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the Borel sets.

Comment: @Asaf: while you are at it, why not also add a tag wiki for descriptive set theory?

Comment: @Willie: Should the tag wiki be descriptive? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure whether you saw that I posted an answer. In any case, please let me know if my answer has any shortcomings or if I failed to address your concerns.

Comment: This is **not** Royden's definition of Baire set.  Like most people, he defines the Baire sets to be the sigma-algebra generated by the _compact_ $G_\delta$ sets.  The sigma-algebra generated by the $G_\delta$ sets is the sigma-algebra of Borel sets.  For a space like the real line the Baire sets coincide with the Borel sets, but this is not true for all spaces, indeed not even for all compact Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definition of the "Baire sets" $\mathcal{B}'$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $G_\delta$-sets, what we obtain **is** the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of Borel sets. The reason is that $\mathcal{B}'$ contains the open sets, as you observed, so $\mathcal{B}' \supseteq \mathcal{B}$ and since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ contains the open sets and is closed under taking countable intersections it follows that $\mathcal{B}$ contains all $G_\delta$-sets, so $\mathcal{B} \supseteq \mathcal{B}'$. Therefore $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}'$ and it would make no sense to distinguish the two concepts.

The usual definition of the Baire $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{Ba}$ (in a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$) is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the **compact** $G_\delta$-sets, or, equivalently, the $\sigma$-algebra making all continuous functions with compact support measurable. Since the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of Borel sets contains all closed sets, it contains all compact subsets of a Hausdorff space, so we always have the inclusion $\mathcal{B} \supseteq \mathcal{Ba}$.

With the first description we can see that in $\mathbb{R}$ the Borel sets and the Baire sets coincide: compact intervals $[a,b]$ are countable intersections of open intervals: $[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, so every compact interval is a compact $G_\delta$, hence $[a,b] \in \mathcal{Ba}(\mathbb{R})$ whenever $a \leq b$. Furthermore, every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a *countable* union of open intervals and every open interval $(a,b)$ can be written as $(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[a+ \frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ which shows that $(a,b) \in \mathcal{Ba}(\mathbb{R})$ and hence $\mathcal{Ba}(\mathbb{R})$ contains all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{Ba}(\mathbb{R}) \supseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

This easily generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, more generally, $\mathcal{Ba}(X) = \mathcal{B}(X)$ holds in every *[second countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space)* locally compact Hausdorff space.

Here are two simple examples you should think about:

1. For every discrete space $X$ we have $$\mathcal{Ba}(X) = \{A \subseteq X : \text{ either } A \text{ is countable or } X \setminus A \text{ is countable}\}$$
   while the $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ is $\mathcal{B}(X) = \mathcal{P}(X)$, the power set of $X$. In particular, $\mathcal{Ba}(X) \subsetneqq \mathcal{B}(X)$ whenever $X$ is uncountable.
2. If you take the [one-point compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-point_compactification) $X^\ast = X \cup \{\infty\}$ of an *uncountable* discrete space $X$ then $\{\infty\} \in X^\ast$ is a standard example of a compact set which is not a $G_\delta$-set.